# Github Repository - License

Tags: git, github

I have created a Github repository that has general information about the use of some programming algorithms in the Readme.md file. Till now it contains just some basic algorithmic concepts but I am planning to make it more animated so the user can understand the concepts and contribute. Should I add any license for now? I was a bit confused about the "No Liability" clause in one the licenses.

Comment: It certainly makes sense especially if you want people to contribute. For tutorial like content it would make sense to use one of the Creative Commons licenses. If you have actual code/software the goes along with it, then there are plenty options like MIT, GPLv3, BSD, ...

Comment: Adding a license lets other programmers know under what conditions it's ok to use your code in their own programs. If you don't, you retain the full copyright on it in most countries, so others can't use it. The GNU project has lots of detailed (albeit biased towards free software) resources on choosing a license: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-recommendations.html https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html

Comment: @mijiturka Thanks for the information. So I think now I have to look for an appropriate license for my repository that has some code files as well a well-documented Readme file.